# Include line comments in cucumber-jvm report

Tags: cucumber-jvm

I  want to include line comments in cucumber jvm report.below is my feature file written in gherkin format:

```
Feature: demo
Scenario: demo scenario
Given page open
When I Login
#Then Page launched
#And some step
```

When above feature file executes and creates a HTML report only without hashtag(#) steps appears in report . Is there any way to include commented steps also in cucumber HTML report.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that requires a change to the reporter. you should give a look to your json output, comments are in there.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i think output tag will come in json report using scenario.write("message") in your '@before' '@after' method implementation

Comment: It's funny, I want to do the opposite in ruby cucumber.

Comment: any answers for this @AdityaK